# Shouldn't the probability of sampling a point from a continuous distribution be 0?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

Hey I was reading about Gaussian EM algorithm in which you first calculate the likelihood of data points being sampled from a Gaussian and then adjust your mean and variance to maximize it. To calculate the probability of a point being sampled from a distribution we do
$$
P(x_i\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$
But how can you sample a point from a continuous distribution? Shouldn't this be zero? Moreover I read many times about sampling a point/data from some continuous distribution but I can't understand how could you do that as for continuous random variable X the $P(X=x_1) = 0 $, so how could yo sample data point(s) from a continuous distribution? Or does this sampling have some other meaning. I've seen many questions on this platform but I couldn't get my answer.

Comment: Hint: Disambiguate **probability** and **probability density**.

Comment: Aren't the continuous r.v described by probability density functions!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392242/basic-understanding-of-sampling-from-a-continuous-distribution discusses it but still I can't understand how can you obtain discrete values from a continuous r.v

Comment: Also this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760681/probability-of-a-point-being-sampled-from-multiple-gaussians discusses it but still I don't understand it

Comment: This is a common paradox that many new students struggle with. [This video could be helpful](https://youtu.be/ZA4JkHKZM50)

Comment: Perhaps also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3666392/442

Comment: (1) The probability is zero.  (2) The $P(x_i \mid \theta)$ is a probability density.  (3) The maximization objective is based on the prob density values, not the probabilities - there is no point in maximizing the probabilities because they are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Decide on the level of accuracy you are working to. For example, if you are modelling masses, you might have the masses being measured to the nearest 5g. That means a measured value of say 45g would in fact be a value between 42.5g and 47.5g. You can then work out the probability that a value is between 42.5g and 47.5g.

Comment: I don't quite see how precision factors into this. The sampled object actually does have one single, infinitely precise value for mass, whether we are able to measure it or not. The probability of sampling an object with mass *exactly* equal to some number is zero. Your point about probability densities integrating over a range to nonzero values is correct, but none of that changes no matter how precise/imprecise your measurement tool is.

Comment: When someone says a data point like 4 is sampled from a continuous distribution then does it mean an interval of $[4-\delta, 4+\delta]$ is sampled from the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

On digital computers, it is certainly impossible to sample from a *truly* continuous distribution; i.e. a distribution that contains infinite possible "discrete" outcomes. One would have to wait an infinite amount of time to compute every one of the infinite decimals. In practice, we chop up the continuous distribution into a discrete number of possibilities and sample from those, and make a case that the discrete distribution adequately represents the continuous distribution.

The simplest example might be a random sampling from a continuous, uniform distribution between values 0 and 1. If we split the interval (0,1) uniformly (chunks of dx) into the infinite number of possibilities, the probability of picking a particular $X$ from $X \in (0,1)$ is

$P(X) = \lim_{dx \to 0} dx=0$

But there's an integral hidden in the denominator:

$\int_{0}^{1}dx = 1$

The integral adds up an infinite number of $dx \to 0$ to get probability 1 of picking *any* number between 0 and 1.

Same thing happens in the numerator for the infinite number of $dx \to 0$ in a finite subinterval, resulting in a non-zero probability for finite subintervals.